# отобразить META тег как текст

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5

Не могу понять как отобразить любой META тег на странице в виде обычного текста.

Если просто вставить его в html-код как есть, то тег, очевидно, будет распарсен браузером и сработает, а нужно просто отобразить пользователю исходный html-код тега как обычный текст.

К примеру, здесь содержимое `div` нужно показать на странице как текст:

```
<div class="meta">
<meta charset="utf-8">
</div>
```

Каким образом можно это сделать? Есть ли какой то способ кроме использования plaintext ?

Comment: откуда отобразить?

Comment: Пишите вопросы понятные не только для себя, но и для нас.

Comment: @n.osennij обновил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте HTML-сущности вместо спецсимволов:

```html
<div class="meta">
&lt;meta charset=&quot;utf-8&quot;&gt;
</div>
```