# Тег в атрибуте (alt="html tag")

Tags: html, css

У меня есть вопрос по HTML.

Как исправить эту ошибку?

```
 <area shape="poly" alt="<img src="folder/image.png">">
```

Comment: конкретнее опишите ошибку

Comment: Подозреваю, что это дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/737750/186083

Comment: Другие кавычки используйте.

Comment: Вы чего вообще хотели добиться таким кодом?

Answer (score 0):

Привет!
Видимо ты не совсем разобрался с использованием , там синтаксис чуть сложнее - по классике нужно ОТДЕЛЬНО задать картинку и поверх нее отрисовать области.

Атрибут alt - он для альтернативного текста для области, не для картинки

Вот ценна ссылка, с примером внутри - https://webref.ru/html/area

Сделай подобно и будет всё работать )

Comment: я хочу добавлять изображения тег с внуторь атрибут ALT="*IMG*

Comment: Как добавить элемент внуторь атрибут ALT? А можна добавляет через Java Script а можна пример?